How to remove black view from VideoView?
I use a tutorial video inside VideoView. But video is not fill VideoView while playing and has black part in VideoView because that has Rectangular view. I can not solution for it. I tried to cover VideoView by CardView and make cardRadius. But It's not remove all black part as properly. How can do this? Can not make VideoView background radius?

VideoFragment.kt
private fun initVideo() {
    simpleVideoView = binding.videoViewTutorial
    simpleVideoView?.setVideoURI(
        Uri.parse("android.resource://" + requireActivity().packageName + "/" + R.raw.tutorial)
    )
    simpleVideoView?.requestFocus()
    simpleVideoView?.start()

}

fragment_video.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/tabContainerUser"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_white_gray_stroke_60dp_radius"
        app:itemIconSize="27dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu_user" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivAskAdvise"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:translationZ="999dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_black_plus_yellow_bg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.63"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewBlackBg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black_0_70"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:translationZ="999dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

<!--    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewVideo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="70dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:translationZ="999dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.80"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.80"
        tools:visibility="visible">-->

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoViewTutorial"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:translationZ="999dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.80"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.80"
        tools:visibility="visible"/>

    <!--</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSkipTutorial"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/mulish_regular"
        android:text="@string/skip"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:translationZ="999dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/videoViewTutorial"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


Try this
vSimpleVideoView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);


I tried before already but I just tried again and it's not working.

Please try one more time
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoViewTutorialN"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.80"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.80"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/videoViewOverlayN"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</FrameLayout>

Java file side - when you want to show the VideoViewT then
videoViewTutorialN.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    videoViewOverlayN.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

otherwise
videoViewTutorialN.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    videoViewOverlayN.setVisibility(View.GONE);


How to use VideoView with constraint layout attributes inside FrameLayout? It does not work.
